# Postgresql, get value for Index[0] in select command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

I am struggling with a Postgresql query. Please refer to the image uploaded with this post.

I am not getting any value at Index[0] for a float[] type field in a select command like

```
Select col(0) as col_0, col(1) as col_1 ..... form table
```

I only get value starting from Index =1, but it is very important for me to have a value on Index(0).

This is a dynamically generated code, can not do Select col(0) as col_1, col(1) as col_2.

Also is there any article on this situation by PGADMIN? Can I get a solid proof that this is a feature issue.

[image]

Comment: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING) the first array element is `[1]`. There is no element `[0]`.

Comment: Thanks very much for quick reply and the link.